# Print image on top of saved photo (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, save, photo, layer

Right now my code just takes a photo and saves it into photo gallery. I would like to have a photo be printed on top of the photo in the bottom right corner of the photo. The photo is called "logo.png". This is just like a lower third on cable news.

```
import UIKit
  import AVFoundation

  class ViewController: UIViewController,AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate  {

var captureSesssion : AVCaptureSession!
var cameraOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput!
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

@IBOutlet var sa: UIView!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()



captureSesssion = AVCaptureSession()
captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
    if (captureSesssion.canAddInput(input)) {
        captureSesssion.addInput(input)
        if (captureSesssion.canAddOutput(cameraOutput)) {
            captureSesssion.addOutput(cameraOutput)
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSesssion)
                previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 700, height: 700)
            sa.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            captureSesssion.startRunning()
        }}}}


      @IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {



      let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
let previewFormat = [
    kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
    kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
    kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
]
settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)


}


func imagex(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {

}

func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,  didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,  previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings:  AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings:   AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {




    if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
        let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
        let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {


        let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
        let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.imagex(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
        } } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a graphic context. Here is a generic example I had on my notes. This is useful to combine images, just adapt it to make it work as you want (That would be settings your custom image (image1 in my case) in the right corner.)

```
var image1 = UIImage(named: "image1.png")
var imageBase = yourImageView.image

var size = yourImageView.frame.size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

let areaSize = CGRect(x: 0, y: size.width - ( size.width / 4 ), width: (size.width / 4), height:( size.height / 4) )
image1!.drawInRect(areaSize)

imageBase!.drawInRect(areaSize, blendMode: CGBlendMode.Normal, alpha: 0.8)

var newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: What function would I put this in imagex or capture? @juanCurti

Comment: It's the same. You should write it when you are sure the image is perfectly saved.

Comment: SO it does not matter if its in capture or imagex it just needs to be in one of those functions. @juanCurti

Comment: I don't know the flow of your application, it depends. If didFinishSavingWithError is called after the photo is saved in Photo Library, I would write it in that one

Comment: the problem is with my code is I don't even know what line of code is saving the image. This code goes from straight uiview to photo gallery. Do you know what line of this code is saving the photo?

Comment: Try writing this code at the end of **capture** function. And be sure to edit it to fit your needs, as it is just an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136114/discussion-between-silly-milly-and-juan-curti).